# This error display when create model for json type 'double' is not a subtype of type 'int' in flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, casting

I create model json from quicktype.io but there not item have type double in object so why this display and those objects from quicktype create

```
 int id;
    String title;
    String description;
    String image;
    String cover;
    String video;
    dynamic promo;
    DateTime displayAt;
    String duration;
    int viewsNum;
    int position;
    int avgWatchTime;
    int likesNum;
    String portalId;
    DateTime createdAt;
    String updatedAt;
    List<dynamic> tags;
```

Comment: You'll have to change it to `double` or `var`. You should also post the Json.

Comment: @ JideGuru can you explain more detail to understand  you

Comment: I meant, you should change the value that's giving the error to "int" or "var".

Comment: @ jideGuru  i change  to var but this error appear flutter: Invalid argument(s)

Comment: Can you post more details in your question? including some JSON?

Comment: i review retrieve json object from postman  and found object called avgWatchTime = 0.0 so this is double finally just change type from int to double and run appear this error (invalid arguments)